# Proof: for a pretty nasty limit

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $$ f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac {[(1x)^2]+[(2x)^2]+\ldots+[(nx)^2]} {n^3}$$.

Prove that f(x) is continuous function.

**Edit**: $[.] $ is the greatest integer function.

Comment: Sri, are the square brackets [ and ] intended to be significant in this problem? As Parth mentions, it is a common notation for the greatest integer function; is this what you intended?

Comment: Is $[.]$ as the floor function??

Comment: @EricStucky, it is so. We were working on the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience it caused to you people. That notation is common in our region. He missed it.

Answer (score 12):

$k^2x^2-1 < [(kx)^2] \le k^2x^2$

Summing the three expressions from $k=1$ to $n$ and dividing by $n^3$, we get
$\frac{x^2}{6}(1+\frac{1}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n}) - \frac{1}{n^2}< \frac{[(1x)^2] + \cdots + [(nx)^2]}{n^3} \le \frac{x^2}{6}(1+\frac{1}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n}) $.

Taking limits as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we get
$\frac{x^2}{3} \le f(x) \le \frac{x^2}{3}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{3}$ which is a continuous function.

(Note that the above, also proves that the limit always exists.)

Comment: I think you missed the factor of 2. It should be $\frac{x^2}{3}$.

Comment: You can calculate the limits without using the sum of squares formula, just by realizing the RHS is the Reimann sum for $\int_0^x x^2 dx$.

Comment: @Thomas: That's clever! But can you actually realize that without the sum of squares formula in the background?

Comment: You just need that $1^2+2^2+3^2 + \dots + n^2 \sim \frac{n^3}{3}$. Not sure how one would prove that, but we prove the general integral $$\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\int_0^{x} t^k dt$$ for any $k$ without knowing how to sum the first $n$ $k$th power. This formula works not just for $k=2$ and $k=100$, but also $k=\sqrt{2}$ and $k=\pi$, and I definitely down know what $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\pi}$ is :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is a known formula for the sum of squares:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Edit: In the case that [.] does mean the greatest integer function, recall that $a-1\leq[a]\leq a$, by definition, and perform both bounds.

Comment: This formula is for sum of the squares of $n$ *consecutive* integers. The sequence is of non-consecutive integers.

Comment: It is *heavily* implied by the question that the sequence is of consecutive integers. I admit that it's *possible* that $1,2,\dots n$ could mean something else, but I'm not interested in considering that possibility without some commentary on the part of OP.

Comment: $1, 2 ... n$ is consecutive. That's fine. What's not fine is the claim that $[(1x)^2], [(2x)^2] \ldots [(nx)^2]$ is the sequence of squares of consecutive numbers.

Comment: I never claimed that it was. The hint still suffices to prove the claim, even if [.] does mean the greatest integer function.

Comment: *"The hint still suffices to prove the claim"*??

Answer (score 1):

In general,
if $[z]$ is the integer part
of $z$,
$D(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n f(kx)
-\sum_{k=1}^n [f(kx)]
=\sum_{k=1}^n (f(kx)-[f(kx)])
$.

Since $0 \le z-[z] < 1$,
$0 \le D(n) < n$.

For your case,
$f(x) = x^2$,
so
$0 \le \sum_{k=1}^n (kx)^2
-\sum_{k=1}^n [(kx)^2]
< n$
or
$0 \le \dfrac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n (kx)^2
-\dfrac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n [(kx)^2]
< \frac{n}{n^3}
=\frac1{n^2}
$.

Therefore,
since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n (kx)^2
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
=\frac{x^2}{3}
$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n [(kx)^2]
=\frac{x^2}{3}
$.